# select rows using pair of columns with JPA (provider eclipselink) and Spring Data

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, eclipselink

I have a table like below in MSSQL -

```
create table t1 (

  id   int   IDENTITY(1,1),
  col1 int   not null,
  col2 int   not null, 
  
  constraint t1_UK UNIQUE (col1, col2)

)
```

and data like below -

```
   id    col1     col2
    1      25      661
    2      25      741
    3      89      661
    4      89      741
```

how do I select rows with id 1 and id 4 with where clause only on col1 and col2 ?

Entity Def-

```
@Entity
@Table
class T1Entity {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private int id;

   @Column
   private int col1;

   @Column
   private int col2;

   // getters, setters
}
```

Note that assuming I have `T1EntityRepository`, I can't define a method like `findByCol1InAndCol2In(List.of(25, 89), List.of(661, 741)` as it will return all rows in sample data.

I know I need something like `Select col1, col2 from t1 where (col1=25 and col2 = 661) OR (col1=89 and col2=741)` but how to do this using JPA. (also, is there a way in SQL itself without using OR of AND)

Comment: This is trivial in JPQL/SQL strings by building a string, or with criteria queries if you dynamically build the query. What you are asking though is how to do it statically with Spring generating the query for you - you cannot. You have to build the query yourself, adding in 'OR' clauses for each pair of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I am writing the custom query using @Query to solve this problem. You can write custom where causes,

```
  @Query("SELECT wftr FROM WorkflowActivityRequestEntity wftr WHERE wftr.status IN :status")
List<WorkflowActivityRequestEntity> findWorkflowActivityRequestsByStatus(
        @Param("status")
        List<String> status);

@Query("SELECT wftr FROM WorkflowActivityRequestEntity wftr WHERE wftr.owner NOT IN :owners")
List<WorkflowActivityRequestEntity> findWorkflowActivityRequestsNotOwnedBy(
        @Param("owners")
        List<String> owners);
```

For AND and OR combination you can also extend your repository interface with `JpaSpecificationExecutor`

and then use Criteria builder. I referred https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-criteria-queries while doing this in my projects.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create an `@Embeddable` class to hold your `col1` and `col2`:

```java
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Embeddable;
import java.io.Serializable;
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class ColWrapper implements Serializable {
  private @Column(name = "col1") Integer col1;
  private @Column(name = "col2") Integer col2;
}
```

Add a field of this type in your entity:

```java
import jakarta.persistence.AttributeOverride;
import jakarta.persistence.AttributeOverrides;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import java.io.Serializable;
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Getter
// Fields should not be modifiable from outside, you can add
// @Setter(AccessLevel.PUBLIC) on those fields that should be modifiable
@Setter(AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@Table(name = "t1")
@Entity
public class T1Entity implements Serializable {
  // Using "strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY" to prevent Hibernate from 
  // creating columns in database upon initialization.
  // Integer is used instead of int here and below to distinguish between
  // uninitialized field and field that has value of 0.
  private @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) Integer id;
  private @Column Integer col1;
  private @Column Integer col2;

  // Needed only to add "updatable=false" and "insertable=false"
  // on @Column annotations for ColWrapper. If you don't want to use
  // ColWrapper anywhere else, you can add "updatable = false" and
  // "insertable = false" in @Column annotations in ColWrapper declaration 
  // and omit the entire @AttributeOverrides annotation here
  @AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(
        name = "col1",
        column = @Column(name = "col1", updatable = false, insertable = false)),
    @AttributeOverride(
        name = "col2",
        column = @Column(name = "col2", updatable = false, insertable = false))
  })
  private ColWrapper colWrapper;

  public T1Entity(int id, int col1, int col2) {
    setId(id);
    setCol1(col1);
    setCol2(col2);
    // Just for consistency
    setColWrapper(new ColWrapper(col1, col2));
  }
```

Spring Data JPA Repository code:

```java
import java.util.List;
import lombok.NonNull;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface T1Repository extends JpaRepository<T1Entity, Long> {
  @NonNull
  List<T1Entity> findByColWrapperIn(@NonNull Iterable<ColWrapper> pairs);
}
```

Sample service:

```
import java.util.List;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class T1Service {
  private final @NonNull T1Repository t1Repository;

  @Transactional
  public void test() {
    final var result =
        t1Repository.findByColWrapperIn(List.of(new ColWrapper(25, 661), new ColWrapper(89, 741)));
    for (var entity : result) {
      System.out.println(entity.getCol1() + ", " + entity.getCol2());
    }
  }
}
```

Calling `test()` should result in this SQL request being (newlines added by me, you can view this SQL in logs if you enable `DEBUG`-level logging for `org.hibernate.SQL` logger):

```sql
select
t1_0.id,
t1_0.col1,
t1_0.col2
from t1 t1_0
where (t1_0.col1,t1_0.col2) in ((?,?),(?,?))
```

Console output:

```
25, 661
89, 741
```

Another way is to use specifications like mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69736182/156973).